# Question on isomorphism between $D_3$ and $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to understand a proof that $D_3 \cong S_3$. I could write out the multiplication tables, which would work, but I think arguing geometrically is the most instructive and what my instructor intended. The sketch I have in my mind is as follows:

> Every symmetry of the equilateral triangle permutes the vertices, so $D_3$ can be regarded as a subgroup of $S_3$, hence there exists an injective homomorphism $f: D_3 \to S_3$. As $|D_3| = 6 = |S_3|$, any injective map of sets is also surjective, so $f$ is a bijective and therefore an isomorphism.

The argument, as I've written it, seems too hand-wavy to me. In particular, I feel that I'm making a leap by equating symmetries of the triangle with permutations, even though they in fact permute the vertices, and I can think of a permutation of a three-element set $\{1,2,3\}$ as vertices $1$, $2$, and $3$, provided that I label them on the triangle. Every symmetry surely permutes the vertices, and in the case of a triangle, every permutation yields a symmetry because every vertex is adjacent to the other two vertices, so no matter how I permute them, distances between vertices is preserved. The "homomorphism" part is what I'm really stuck with. I have an intuitive sense that the diagram of maps must commute, and I could prove by brute force, by checking all of the pairs of elements of $D_3$, that it does, but I don't have a very good way to prove that the composition laws agree.

I'd appreciate any help in parsing this.

Comment: Generators and relations. Prove that each group is generated by two elements, call them $a$ and $b$, such that $a^2=b^3=1$ and $ab=b^2a$. Deduce that the two groups are isomorphic.

Comment: The group operation in both $S_3$ and $D_3$ is the composition of functions (permutations in one case, symmetries in the other). That's a proof of the homomorphism property right there. Only then proceed with injectivity/surjectivity.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm able to prove this fact, but how then do I deduce that the groups are isomorphic? Is it enough to say, "they obey the same defining relations, so they're isomorphic"?

Comment: It is enough – provided that you understand *why* it is enough. The entire group table can be reconstructed from the generators and relations, so if two groups share generators and relations, they have the same group table, so they are isomorphic.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see. So is the idea that the isomorphism sends generators to generators, and the remainder of the map is uniquely determined? The other thing I'm stumbling on a bit is proving it is a bijection of sets. I'm not able to convince myself if it's possible for two groups to obey the same defining relations but not be in bijection as sets and therefore not isomorphic.

Comment: I've written it up in some detail & posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group is determined, up to isomorphism, by its generators and relations. In other words, if two groups have the same description in terms of generators and relations, then the two groups are isomorphic. Let's see how this works out in the case at hand.

Each group can be described as being generated by $a$ and $b$ with the relations $a^2=b^3=1$ and $ab=b^2a$. For the group of symmetries of a triangle, you can take $a$ to be any flip and $b$ to be any rotation one-third of the way around. For the symmetric group on three symbols, you can take $a$ to be any transposition, and $b$ to be any $3$-cycle.

Knowing that $a$ and $b$ generate a group $G$ tells you that every element of $G$ is of the form $a^{r_1}b^{r_2}a^{r_3}b^{r_4}\dotsb a^{r_{n-1}}b^{r_n}$ for some nonnegative integer $n$ and some integers $r_1,r_2,\dotsc,r_n$. Knowing that $ab=b^2a$ allows you to move any $b$ that is to the right of an $a$ to the left of that $a$, at the cost of replacing $b$ by $b^2$. It follows that every element of $G$ can be written as $b^sa^t$ for some integers $s,t$. Knowing that $a^2=b^3=1$ tells you that every element of $G$ can be written as $b^sa^t$ with $s$ in $\{0,1,2\}$ and $a$ in $\{0,1\}$.

So we now know that as a set, $G=\{1,b,b^2,a,ba,b^2a\}$. But we also know how to multiply any two elements of $G$. For example, $(ba)(b^2a)=babba=bb^2aba=b^3aba=aba=b^2aa=b^2a^2=b^2$. So we have deduced the entire structure of the group, the whole multiplication table, from the generators and relations.

Answer (score 2):

If you agree that:
$$D_n=\langle s,r\mid s^2=r^n=1, sr=r^{-1}s\rangle$$
and have group action at hands, then both the "homomorphism part" and the injectivity come easy. In fact, every group $G$ *acts* (homomorphism!) by left multiplication on the left quotient set $G/H$, for every subgroup $H\le G$, and the kernel of this action is the normal core of $H$ in $G$, namely the intersection of all the conjugates of $H$ in $G$. Now, $D_n$ has the subgroup $H:=\{1,s\}$, whose index and normal core in $G$ are $n$ and (for $n>2$) the trivial subgroup $\{1\}$, respectively. In fact, $r^{-1}Hr=\{1,r^{-1}sr\}=\{1,sr^2\}$, and $sr^2\ne s$ as soon as $n>2$ (because then $r^2\ne 1$), so that $H\cap r^{-1}Hr=\{1\}$. This suffices to ensure that the normal core is trivial and hence the action is faithful (equivalently, the homomorphism is injective).